# Can't add a Connected App to a Package

Tags: managed-package, appexchange, connected-apps

I have an external service that I would like to offer on Salesforce via their marketplace.

As I understand, I need to create a Connected app and use the oAuth APIs to connect to the Salesforce system. Once I have this setup, I can create a Package and distribute it in the marketplace.

I'm going through the paces, trying to make sure my assumptions are correct (is there anything I'm missing?).

However, I ran into a problem

1. I've created a Connected App entry in the App Manager and it shows up as 'Connected'
2. I've created a package in the Package Manager and it too shows up properly
3. I open the Package Manager and go into Setup, but I can't add the Connected App into the Package.

When I select 'Apps' from the dropdown, my Connected app doesn't appear. Do I need to do something else for the app to appear?

[image: Package manager view]

Comment: Strictly speaking, this method of installing connected apps is obsolete; the first time a user in an org uses it, it automatically appears in the Setup menu, and can then be installed/configured/blocked by an administrator.

Comment: Is your org namespaced ?

Comment: @sfdcfox So how do you distribute the app on the Appexchange without packaging it? I want the app to be listed there,

Comment: @MohithShrivastava I don't think so. Is that required?

Comment: @JohnP Yes please .Check my answer .You need to namespace and then create a managed type of application .

Comment: @MohithShrivastava Yes, but I have a namespaced package org, and I'm not able to package a ConnectedApp, either.

Comment: Connected apps thats installed wont be available but the one that one has developed in the packaging org should be available for the package .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aren't connected apps listed in the "Connected App" component type drop down menu not the "App" one.

You just need to switch the drop down.

Comment: Actually, you're partly right! The 'Connected App' option doesn't seem to show up till you set the namespace as described here : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/namespaces_creating.htm Once you do setup the namespace, the Connected App option shows up and you can select it and the app appears. Thanks!

Comment: I had the same issue but a little bit different. I marked the package as 'managed' but get the error message that I is not possible to have more than one managed package in one Org (but I had no other managed package in this org). When I do not select it as a managed package the Option 'Connected App' do not appear in the drop down. So the solution was: Do not mark it as 'Managed package' on the first step-> add all other relevant components and than on the next screen edit the package again and mark it as 'Managed package'. And...The menu appears in the Dropdown